# Reversing edges in a digraph

Tags: python, graph

I have a dictionary of edges as follows;

```
edges={vertex1:[(neighbor1,weight1),(n2,w2),...],v2:[(neighbork,weightk).....vk:[(),()]}
```

Does anyone know a way of reversing the edges in O(E)? I can only think of a nested for approach which is definitely not right.

For example:

```
{0:[(1,5),(2,3)],1:[(2,2)]}
```

which is a graph where edges are 0->1 (weight 5), 0->2 (weight 3) , 1->2 (weight 2)

after reversing becomes;

```
{1:[(0,5)],2:[(0,3),(1,2)]}
```

which is a graph where edges are 1->0 (weight 5), 2->0 (weight 3) , 2->1 (weight 2)

Comment: Can you give a simple example of your desired output here?

Comment: What's wrong with creating a new graph by adding your reversed edges 1 by 1?

Comment: @JulienBernu But creating a new graph would also essentially have the same operations required for reversing edges right? I am not against using another dict to represent a new reversed graph, but how?

Comment: I don't really see a way to do what you're asking in less than `O(<num edges> * <num weights>)` time, which is what John Zwinck's solution below is.

Comment: I was thinking exactly what John Zwinck wrote. @ Nolen Royalty, unless I'm misunderstanding something this is O(E) even if there are 2 for loops: every edge is visited / reversed only once. `num edges` and `num weights` are the same. And to write it in a loose way corresponding to the nested for loops, we have `num edges = num vertices * num edge per vertex`.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

g = {0:[(1,5),(2,3)],1:[(2,2)]}
r = defaultdict(list)

for origin, targets in g.iteritems():
    for target, weight in targets:
        r[target].append((origin, weight))
```

Now `r` is basically your answer.  You can do `dict(r)` at the end to get a regular dict instead of the defaultdict if you need.

Comment: OP specifically asks for a solution in `O(E)` time, but afaik that isn't really possible here: this is the best solution.  +1

Comment: @Nolen Royalty, please explain your reasoning.

Comment: @JulienBernu I misunderstood what you were asking and thought you wanted the algorithm to not depend on the number of weights per edge (which afaik is impossible).  Reading your comment above this solution is exactly what you're looking for, and I recommend you accept it :)

Comment: It's not my question, but yes the answer should be accepted :)